# HyperLedgerFabric　An error occurred when installing chaincode

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

An error occurs during the installation of the chain code.

```
Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build failed: docker build failed: Failed to pull hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:2.2: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
Chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed
Deploying chaincode failed
```

In the Docker Desktop settings, I unchecked Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing.
There is an error earlier.
I would like to know the solution to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Fabric v2.5, only amd64 Docker images were published. From Fabric v2.5, both amd64 and arm64 Docker images are built and published. See the [Fabric documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/whatsnew.html) for key changes / features in each version.

If you cannot move to Fabric v2.5, you can manually pull the hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:2.2 Docker images with the [--platform option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) to specify amd64, and then rely on emulation within Docker to run the container. For example:

```
docker pull --platform amd64 hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:2.2
```

Since the image is already present, the chaincode install process will not trigger a pull of the image using your default (arm64) architecture.